# How to read json object and how to store it in buffer or byte array in java

Tags: java, json

Can anyone please tell me how to read jsonObject and how to store it into buffer.
For that I have written few lines but they are not working

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

Object object = parser.parse(new FileReader("D:/msg.json"));

JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)object;

byte[] objAsBytes = jsonObject.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Please help me to get it done.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to store the json object in a buffer? Add some info about the requirement.

Comment: I just want it for creating digital signature of json file.